# Problem with Laravel Eloquent Where , orWhere and Find in a same eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

How can I write this query with Laravel Eloquent
`"SELECT * FROM links WHERE (user_id = 1 OR user_ip = '127.0.0.1') AND id = 53 LIMIT 1"`

I have written this one:
`

```
$link = Link::query()
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->orWhere('user_ip', \request()->ip())
            ->with('clicks')
            ->findOrFail($id);
```

And the SQL version of this one is : `"SELECT * FROM links WHERE user_id = 1 OR user_ip = '127.0.0.1'  AND id = 53 LIMIT 1"`;

Its shows always unexpected result like :
It shows the result of id 51 every time even when id is 52,53,54 but the result is shown for Id 51.

Thank you
Tamim

Comment: Can you edit your question with your database structure and data from the relevant table?

Comment: have you taken into account that there is a OR condition as well, AND is executed first then OR condtion

Comment: I got the solution guys, Thanks for replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group conditions when you pass a closure to `where`.

```php
$link = Link::query()
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->orWhere('user_ip', \request()->ip())
    })
    ->with('clicks')
    ->findOrFail($id);
```